# flutter audio_service, how to set an interval between two audios

Tags: flutter, avplayer, just-audio, audio-service, flutter-audio-query

I make a looping function and support running in background, so I choose audio_service and just_audio.

But I want to control the interval between two audios playing.

I hope the first one has finished playing, set 1 second and then play the second effect and I'm new to flutter and hope to get help, thank you！

[image]

This is the raw effect.

```
class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler {

  ...

  @override
  Future<void> play() async {
    sleep(Duration(seconds:1));

    _player.play();
  }
```

I tried adding a sleep to the override play function but it didn't work.I'm guessing that the looping is internally cached or something, I don't know。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
  @override
  Future<void> play() async {

     await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:1));
    _player.play();
  }
```

Comment: I tried this method, it can sleep when playing alone, but when it is playing in a loop, it may be loaded at one time internally, so the audio will not call the play method every time, causing sleep to not work.